# java.io.EOFException when parsing JSON with clojure Transit

Tags: json, clojure, transit

I am reading from an input stream with `(t/read request-body :json)`
 and I get a `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException`.

```
{"A":"B", "C":"D"}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
                   ReaderFactory.java:122 com.cognitect.transit.impl.ReaderFactory$ReaderImpl.read
                  TransitFactory.java:136 com.cognitect.transit.TransitFactory$DeferredJsonReader.read
                          transit.clj:285 cognitect.transit/read
```

Any ideas why this could be?

For clarity the curl POST request:

```
%curl -X POST ...../word -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"A":"B", "C":"D"}' -v > abc.html 
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--     --:--:--     0*   Trying 178.63.65.149...
* Connected to ..... (178.63.65.149) port 80 (#0)
> POST /word HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: .....
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 18
> 
} [data not shown]
* upload completely sent off: 18 out of 18 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
* Server nginx/1.2.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.2.1
< Date: Sat, 04 Apr 2015 19:05:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 13190
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
{ [data not shown]
100 13208  100 13190  100    18  79062    107 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 79457
* Connection #0 to host ..... left intact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your logging data, your request body is not actually json, it looks like a multi-part/form-data encoded form which includes a json file-upload.

Comment: thanks, I changed the post request's type using curl and updated the question accordingly

Comment: OK that looks better. Note that you can read a request body only once. If your code prints the body for debugging  and then tries to read it again for parsing that will give an EOF error.